# How to set a static integer to zero?

Tags: java

The lesson is:

> In this exercise, we will be looking at our example code for Selection
>   Sort.  However, while we are sorting we will also count the number of
>   swaps taking place, then print them out once the array has been
>   sorted.
>
> Add a print statement at the end of the selectionSort method that
>   prints out the number of swaps that took place during the sort.
>
> You should not modify the run() method.
>
> Hint: where are items compared? Try writing out the steps in the
>   algorithm on paper to help.

My code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SelectionSort extends ConsoleProgram
{

private static int count;

public void run()
{
    int[] array1 = {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    int[] array2 = {5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 7, 3, 1, 2};

    System.out.print("First array: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
    System.out.print("Second array: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));
    System.out.println();

    // sort first array
    selectionSort(array1);
    // sort second array
    selectionSort(array2);

    System.out.print("First array sorted: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
    System.out.print("Second array sorted: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));
}

/*
 * Selection sort takes in an array of integers and
 * returns a sorted array of the same integers.
 */
public static int[] selectionSort(int[] arr)
{
    int currentMinIndex;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
    {
        currentMinIndex = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
        {
            if(arr[j] < arr[currentMinIndex])
            {
                currentMinIndex = j;
            }
        }

        // swap numbers if needed
        if (i != currentMinIndex)
        {
            int temp = arr[currentMinIndex];
            arr[currentMinIndex] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
            count++;
        }
    }
    // Print out the number of swaps that took place here
    // before returning arr
    System.out.println(count);
    return arr;
}
}
```

And the problem is, I need **int count** to set to zero after each selectionSort instead of keep adding on, and I could not find a way to do it.

Comment: Err, `count = 0;`? Is this such a mystery?

Comment: @EJP tell that to Scooby, Shaggy and the Gang.

Comment: set count to zero after printing it.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this before and it returned error, but this time it works,...I guess probably I typed something wrong last time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set count to 0 at the end of every iteration.

`System.out.println(count);
count = 0;
return arr;`